# MongoDB invalid file error

Tags: mongodb

I have mongo .ns file having length of 16777217 (not multiple of 1024 * 1024).if I start mongo instance, it gives me error that invalid file size. Ideally the ns file should be multiple of 1024*1024. Not sure how it got created. Any suggestions ?

Error log:

> 2017-06-16T09:31:30.634+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten] Invalid length: 16777217 for .ns file: /var/lib/mongodb/mytestDB.ns. Cannot open database
>   2017-06-16T09:31:30.635+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] database /var/lib/mongodb/ mytestDB could not be opened due to DBException 10079: Invalid length: 16777217 for .ns file: /var/lib/mongodb/mytestDB.ns. Cannot open database
>   2017-06-16T09:31:30.635+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10079 Invalid length: 16777217 for .ns file: /var/lib/mongodb/mytestDB.ns. Cannot open database, terminating
>   2017-06-16T09:31:30.635+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
>   2017-06-16T09:31:30.635+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
>   2017-06-16T09:31:30.635+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
>   2017-06-16T09:31:30.635+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
>   2017-06-16T09:31:30.635+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
>   2017-06-16T09:31:30.638+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
>   2017-06-16T09:31:30.638+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
>   2017-06-16T09:31:30.654+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] old journal file /var/lib/mongodb/journal/j._0 will be reused as /var/lib/mongodb/journal/prealloc.0
>   2017-06-16T09:31:30.686+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] Terminating durability thread ...
>   2017-06-16T09:31:30.738+0000 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread stopped
>   2017-06-16T09:31:30.738+0000 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread stopped
>   2017-06-16T09:31:30.738+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...

Comment: If you have an error, you should at least provide the full stacktrace of the error. Also you should provide more information about the context.

Comment: added logs and answer as well

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this problem. Ideally the file size should be multiple of 1MB. In this case it was 1B more than 16MB. I truncated the file size to 16MB and mongod instance started working again.

### unix command:

truncate --size=16M mytestDB.ns

Comment: I kept backup of the file before truncating. The total size reduced is only 1Byte. So far all the data looks good. But it is still a question that how come size of the file was not in multiples of 1MB.